# Google Earth Engine - Filter for FeatureCollection WCMC/WDPA

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I am working with FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons') and ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_ANNUAL_EVI').  I would like to add a filter to  the WCMC/WDPA data to display only Parks Canada protected areas.  I have tried the following code lines with no success.

```
.filterMetadata('country', 'equals', 'Canada')  
.filterMetadata('MANG_AUTH', 'equals', Parks Canada);
```

The following two scripts load successfully.

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons')
var visParams = {
  palette: ['2ed033', '5aff05', '67b9ff', '5844ff', '0a7618', '2c05ff'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1550000.0,
  opacity: 0.8,
};  
var image = ee.Image().float().paint(dataset, 'REP_AREA');  
Map.setCenter(41.104, -17.724, 6);  
Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons');  
Map.addLayer(dataset, null, 'for Inspector', false);  
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_ANNUAL_EVI')
                  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');  
var colorized = dataset.select('EVI');  
var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};  
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 6);
Map.addLayer(colorized, colorizedVis, 'Colorized');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Parks Canada as an entry of "MANG_AUTH" is labeled "Parks Canada / Ministère des Forêts, de la Faune et des Parcs", which is likely why your filter did not work. Additionally, the "WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons" FeatureCollection does not contain a property titled: "country".

The `ee.Filter.stringContains` collection filter can be helpful if you are unsure of the exact name of a property entry of interest:

```js
// Import the protected areas FeatureCollection.
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons');

// Filter to 'MANG_AUTH' eq 'Parks Canada' using stringContains..
var parksCanada = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('MANG_AUTH', 'Parks Canada'));

// Map the features.
Map.addLayer(parksCanada);
```

To see a full list of available entries for a property, you can use something like this to print the unique list.

```js
print(ee.List(dataset.aggregate_array('MANG_AUTH')).distinct().sort());
```